# Does the rate reaction of clock reaction increase over time?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

I'm studing the following version of iodine clock reaction, in which, $[\ce{H_2O_2}]_0$ > [ascorbic acid]$_0$

$$\ce{I^- + H_2O_2 -> I_2}$$

$$\ce{I2 + ascorbic acid -> I- + side products}$$

When the concentration of ascorbic acid is zero, also known as induction period,

$$\ce{I2 + I- -> I3-}$$
$$\ce{I3- + starch -> blue complex}$$

During the first moment I thought that due to the abrupt occurrence of the product, the rate reaction must increase after the induction period. But after doing some research I realized that the occurrence of the product is actually due to the stoichiometric constraint of ascorbic acid.

So, now I think that the rate reaction of a clock reaction decreases over time and that the concentration of products only increases due to the stoichiometric constraint. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Chemistry.SE! Could you please edit your question and format the chemical formulae and equations with MathJax, so that they are more readable? A handy guide for MathJax on this site is here: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange

Comment: Done it, thank you for the advise @ShoubhikRMaiti ^^

Comment: You can write a whole formula inside one ``$\ce{}$`` to get this  ``$\ce{I2 + I- -> I3-}$`` is displayed as $\ce{I2 + I- -> I3-}$ ``$$   $$`` gives you the center aligned text, $$\ce{I2}$$

Comment: What happens in detail of course depends on the rate constants and concentrations but with similar rate constants for reaction of $I^-$ and $I_2$ the iodine ($I_2$) concentration rapidly rises and then falls more slowly to virtually zero, the $I^-_3$ gradually increases until it reaches a steady value. The reaction stops when all the iodine is consumed by forming the product.